# How to evaluate the integral $\displaystyle\int \frac{x^{15}}{{(1+x^3)^{\frac{2}{5}}}} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

We were given this integral in one textbook for our high school calculus class. I tried applying all possible methods, however nothing worked. Can you give me some advice on how to approach this problem. $$\int \frac{x^{15}}{{(1+x^3)^{\frac{2}{5}}}} dx = \int \frac{x^{15}}{\sqrt[5]{(1+x^3)^2}} dx$$

Edit: The task comes from our calculus book, however it asks for solving the definite integral, however we must still solve the indefinite and apply the formula to get the value then.

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt[4]{2}} \frac{x^{15}}{{(1+x^3)^{\frac{2}{5}}}} dx $$

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? Seeing [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E%2815%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E3%29%5E%282%2F5%29) failing (i.e. returning something non-elementary) isn't a good sign in general.

Comment: Was this an indefinite integral?

Comment: Yes, here is the exact picture of the integral our teacher said we should try to solve: https://imgur.com/a/sRLg6ta exactly the same as the above

Comment: Well, it is hand-written, so there is always the possibility of a mistake. For instance, if the coefficient of $x$ in the numerator was $5$, or $14$, then the substitution $u=1+x^3$ would work nicely.

Comment: If you change 15 by 14 you get an elementary solution....

Comment: It is from our calculus book, and it is correctly copied, however the book asks for solving the definite integral from 0 to $\sqrt[4]{2}$

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Some definite integrals cannot be obtained from the indefinite expressions. What is your chapter about ?

Comment: It is just definite integrals, we are just studying basic integrals.

Comment: OK, now I suspect that the misprint is $1+x^3$ instead of $1+x^4$. Does your calculus book have answers to the problems?

Comment: According to the solutions given in the book, it says that the result should be $\frac{5}{64}(\sqrt[3]{125} - 1)$, a value close to 0.127

Comment: Well, this is a mystery. I tried my suggested misprint of $1+x^4$ and I didn't get anything resembling your answer. If what you say is correct, the book seems to have made a mistake.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, $\frac{5}{64}(\sqrt[3]{125}-1)$ is exactly $0.3125$, which is not close to $0.127$.

Comment: @someone123123 Your result is just $$\frac 5{16}=.3125$$

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let’s use @user$170231$’s result:

> $$3\,{}_2F_1\left(\frac25,\frac{16}3;\frac{19}3;-\sqrt[4]8\right)$$

which is just:

$$3\,{}_2\text F_1\left(\frac25,\frac{16}3;\frac{16}3+1;-\sqrt[4]8\right) $$

and by the use of the [**following identity**](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/):

$$\,_2\text F_1(a,b,b+1,z)=\frac b{z^b}\text B_z(b,1-a)$$

Therefore:

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt[4]{2}} \frac{x^{15}}{{(1+x^3)^{\frac{2}{5}}}} dx = 3\,_2\text F_1\left(\frac25,\frac{16}3;\frac{16}3+1;-\sqrt[4]8\right) =(-1)^\frac 23 \text B_{-2^\frac34}\left(\frac{16}3,\frac35\right)= 2.11380849407852224338555434770918887014885712827... $$

as shown [**in this computation**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29+beta%28-2%5E%283%2F4%29%2C+16%2F3%2C+3%2F5%29). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{x^{15}}{(1+x^3)^{2/5}}\,\mathrm dx$$

Let $u=1+x^3$, so that $x=(u-1)^{1/3}$ and $\mathrm dx=\frac13(u-1)^{-2/3}\,\mathrm du$. Then the integral becomes

$$\frac13\int\frac{(u-1)^5}{u^{2/5}}(u-1)^{-2/3}\,\mathrm du=\frac13\int(u-1)^{13/3}u^{-2/5}\,\mathrm du$$

which almost resembles the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). However, you mention in the comments that the original integral is taken over the set $x\in[0,\sqrt[4]2]$, so the latter integral is taken over $u\in[1,1+\sqrt[4]8]$ and has a value of

$$\frac13\int_1^{1+\sqrt[4]8}(u-1)^{13/3}u^{-2/5}\,\mathrm du=3\,{}_2F_1\left(\frac25,\frac{16}3;\frac{19}3;-\sqrt[4]8\right)\approx2.11381$$

(computation courtesy of *Mathematica*) where ${}_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). I wouldn't expect this to have an elementary form, so perhaps there is an error made by the author or your instructor.

Comment: According to the solutions given in the book, it says that the result should be $\frac{5}{64}(\sqrt[3]{125} - 1)$, a value close to 0.127

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{125}$ is just $5$. There must be a typo.